# Dojo buttons not rendering correctly in IE 7

Tags: internet-explorer, dojo, rendering, button, label

This only happens on Internet Explorer 7 or IE 8 compatibility mode: the button labels appear in the wrong place on the page, but when I place the cursor over them, the label appears in the right place.

I attached some screen shots.

[Screenshot of IE buttons labels in wrong place http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/edf8cb8bc6.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/edf8cb8bc6.png)

Comment: How are you positioning the buttons and what is the DOM structure?  Have you tried to reduce this to a simpler test case to rule out other interactions?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a clear after the TabContainer DIV. Looks like a floating issue caused when Dojo re-sizes the ContentPane.